# Dynamically highlight table row by selected element in React 16 component

Tags: reactjs, react-16

In React 16 I have a table, I need to highlight a row of the table (set a CSS class to it) based on the fact that a certain form element (radio button) located in that row of the table has been selected. After selecting an element, the component is redrawn and I know the value of the selected element.

Is there any way in React 16 to dynamically set a CSS class without using e.g. jQuery and similar libraries? I don't have much of code to show, if necessary I will elaborate in answering questions.